# What mistake am I making while casting?

Tags: python

I am getting an error in the line thats trying to calculate the value of calc

```
num1 = input("Enter first number:")
num2 = input("Enter second number:")
num3 = input("Enter third number:")

print("Output:")
calc = float((num1 + num2 + num3)/ 2)
print("{0}+{1}+{2})/2 is:{3}".format(num1,num2,num3,calc))
```

This is what I went with thanks for the help...

```
num1 = float(input("Enter first number:"))
num2 = float(input("Enter second number:"))
num3 = float(input("Enter third number:"))

print("Output:")
calc = ((num1 + num2 + num3)/ 2)
print("{0}+{1}+{2})/2 is:{3}".format(num1,num2,num3,calc))
```

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Input return strings! So, convert the three numbers by `int`! And as comment said, better converting directly in float.

```
num1 = float(input("Enter first number:"))
num2 = float(input("Enter second number:"))
num3 = float(input("Enter third number:"))

print("Output:")
calc = (num1 + num2 + num3)/ 2
print("{0}+{1}+{2})/2 is:{3}".format(num1,num2,num3,calc))

>>> 
Result:
Enter first number:12
Enter second number:2
Enter third number:5
Output:
12+2+5)/2 is:9.5
>>>
```

Comment: Converting to floats may be more appropriate in case the user types a decimal number.

Comment: thanks..would making them floats be better and then leaving out the float in the calc line be better?

Comment: @JerryMurphy in python3x you get a float anyway. You'd get an integer result with the `//` operator.

Comment: @Ray and JerryMurphy: I've just edited my answer. Thanks